# Can anybody please explain the below program?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
    <input id="age">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>    
<script>
        function myFunction() 
        {
            var a;
            age = document.getElementById('age').value;
            a = (age < 18) ? "Too Young" : "Old Enough";
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = a + "To Vote";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I am unable to understand "age = document.getElementById('age').value" and what actually ".value" function does??? Can Anyone Explain Briefly Please??

Comment: `age = document.getElementById('age').value` will get the value entered in the element with id `age`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program is trying to simply validate the age and draw a conclusion. But it has got some code to take care

1) `age` is not defined as a var. So it will be taken as a global variable, which may create mess. So a varibale should always accompanied with a var keyword, which also defines the scope of it.

2) `(age < 18) ? "Too Young" : "Old Enough";`
   This is ternary operator. Think of case like this

```
if(age<18){
     "Too Young"
  }
  else{
   "Old Enough"
  }
```

Instead of using loop `'?'` is validating if age is less than 18. If true then "Too Young" . (`:`) is or operator.So if age is not less than 18 then "Old Enough".Once `a` variable is set this line `document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = a + "To Vote";` 
is use to append the result.JS will look for a DOM element with id `demo` and `innerHTML` will append the text in it.

Answer (score 0):

It gets the `value` of the element with `id` `age`.

So in your case you have a `input` with the `id` `age` on click of the submit button it will run the function and get the value.

**Reading Material**

[`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Answer (score 0):

You have a textbox on your page with the ID of `age`. You also have a button called Submit on the page too. Once you select the Submit button, it calls a javascript function where the variable `a` is defined as whatever value is in the age textbox. It then does a check on the age to see if the value is greater or less than 18. Depending on the result, you'll get some text printed to the screen in the p tag saying either Too Young or Old Enough. The `.value` is simply getting the value of that textbox